# How would I route this hierarchy

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I am creating an app that tracks a users employments and where they are in the companies. I need some help trying to route the app, I has made scaffolds of `user`, `company`, and `department`.

- `user`

  - `company` (user has_many :through => employments)

    - `department`

user.rb

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
    #associations
    has_many :employments
    has_many :companies, :through => :employments
    has_one :department, :through => :employments
end
```

employment.rb

```
class Employment < ActiveRecord::Base

  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :company
  belongs_to :department
  has_many   :employment_histories
end
```

employment_history.rb

```
class EmploymentHistory < ActiveRecord::Base

  belongs_to :employment
end
```

company.rb

```
class Company < ActiveRecord::Base

  has_many :employments
  has_many :users, :through => :employments
  has_many :departments
end
```

department.rb

```
class Department < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :company
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For routing, the simplest way to do it is to declare your resources as resources, and then you access them through the id of the object. 
http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#resource-routing-the-rails-default

Then to find through associations, I suggest you check out this railscast: http://railscasts.com/episodes/3-find-through-association?view=asciicast

If routing and finding through associations doesn't come easily, you will probably want to refactor your hierarchy to make more sense metaphorically. For instance my approach would be:

- User has_many :employments and give it default_scope order: 'employments.created_at DESC' in the User model to make sure the most recent employment is first.
- Employment has_one :department
- Department belongs_to :company
- Company has_many :departments

Then you can access all of this data through associations (see link above). You only need to route the resources, and then know how to access them in the right controllers.

Comment: With your approach, how would hiring/firing go?

Comment: Well, you could make a new Employment for each hiring, and have a nil end-date, and then firing would give the employment an end-date, thus suggesting it is over.